# FTP rule for NACL in AWS

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, ftp, tcp

I need to connect to an external FTP service that resides outside of my VPC boundaries. I added an outbound rule to a specific IP address and both TCP ports: 20 and 21

**Do I need to add and inbound rule as well for both same ports?**

My doubt is around TCP connection:  since TCP is connection oriented my guess is that I need it.

(I cannot make tests so far)

Answer (score 1):

Security groups are stateful in that you would only need to add the outwards rule. NACLs are stateless so you need to add in rules as well as out rules. Most AWS people use security groups in preference to NACLs because the automatic return traffic makes it simpler.

With NACLs ephemeral ports ([explanation here](https://documentation.meraki.com/MX/NAT_and_Port_Forwarding/Active_and_Passive_FTP_Overview_and_Configuration) and [another here](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2558619/understanding-the-ftp-protocol.html)) need to be opened to allow return traffic. Read the links, FTP doesn't work as expected. Those ports vary a bit based on your OS ([Wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port)) tells us

> The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) suggests the range
> 49152 to 65535 (215+214 to 216−1) for dynamic or private ports.[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port)
>
> Many Linux kernels use the port range 32768 to 60999.

Best allow ports 49152 to 65535 inwards on your NACLs to allow FTP to work.

Comment: Thank you @Tim .  Weird situation then:  I implemented outbound in NACL for 20 and 21 and it's working. So if you said that I should also have inbound; why is it working?

Comment: From memory I think NACLs default to inbound is permitted. Did you check if NACLs are open or closed? And if they're open what ports are open?